# Equivalence of uniform convergence and convergence of sup-norm

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

$f_n$ is a sequence of functions ($\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$), and $f_n \rightarrow f$ (uniform convergence). The lecturer in my elementary analysis course seems to often use $f_n \rightarrow f$ and $\lVert f_n-f \rVert_{\sup} \rightarrow 0$ interchangeably. 
 
I get that $\lVert f_n-f \rVert_{\sup} \rightarrow 0$ leads to $f_n \rightarrow f$, since for all $\lVert f_n-f \rVert \leq \lVert f_n-f \rVert_{\sup}$ What troubles me is the other direction. 
 
My reasoning for why $f_n \rightarrow f$ implies $\lVert f_n-f \rVert_{\sup} \rightarrow 0$ is as follows. 
If $f_n \rightarrow f$ holds then that means $\forall \epsilon >0,\hspace{0.1in}\exists N\in \mathbb {N} \hspace{0.1in}s.t. \hspace{0.1in} n\geq N \Rightarrow \lVert f_n - f\rVert < \epsilon $, thus $\lVert f_n-f \rVert_{\sup} \leq \epsilon$, hence $\lVert f_n-f \rVert_{\sup} \rightarrow 0$. Is this correct? My TA seems to use $\lVert f_n-f \rVert_{\sup} \lt \epsilon$ rather than $\leq \epsilon$, and this troubles me. sup-norm could be equal to epsilon under certain situations, right?

Comment: What does $\|a_n-a\|_{\text{sup}}$ mean? For each individual $n$, $a_n-a$ is just a single real number. And if it means $\sup\{|a_n-a|\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$, then $\|a_n-a\|_{\text{sup}}$ is just a number, not a sequence.

Comment: I have edited the question, sorry for the late check.

Comment: What does “uniform convergence” mean for numerical sequences?

Comment: I've changed them to sequence of functions. What I originally meant was sequence of numerical sequences, I should have specified it.

Comment: When you write $\|f_n-f\|\leqslant\|f_n-f\|_\sup$, which norm is the norm on the left?

Comment: euclidean norm? These functions all have real number values.

Comment: Euclidean norm? What does that mean here? What's the Euclidean norm of, say, the exponential function? Or of the sine function?